# Printing pdfs including AcroJS in C#

Tags: c#, pdf, adobe-reader

I searched houres about, how I can print a pdf silently from C# including AcroJs. 
I know there are solutions for it, like starting AdobeReader as Process by CommandLine and Print the document. (http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/598424/How-to-Silently-Print-PDFs-using-Adobe-Reader-and)

But this solutions always open the Reader. Even if you can hide the window,depending on the speed of your computer, you can see the adobe reader window a few seconds. I need a workaround which doesn't open the reader but process the AcroJS forms in pdf jut like the normal reader.

Do you konw any alternatives oder libs, that I can use?
How do I print PDFs silently with procesing AcroJS and wthout open the Adobe Reader process in c#?

Thanks :)

Comment: Check out these guys: http://www.evopdf.com/

Comment: Evopdf seems to be god, but I don't find silen Printing there yet.

Answer (score 0):

Your application need to be built using the Adobe Reader OCX or some PDF library. Then, the application needs to be configured to use a default printer. It can then be issued commands to print documents without showing a window.

Comment: Thanks :) i tried out using the adobe OCX from C# but it's very difficult to understand how it works... In my case the OCX wrapper doesn't work very well..

Comment: You can try our product XtremeDocumentStudio .NET ViewPrintConvert edition. http://www.gnostice.com/nl_article.asp?id=280&t=Print_PDF_DOC_DOCX_and_images_with_XtremeDocumentStudio_NETs_multi_format_document_printer_control

Comment: Thanks for this solution but the lib doesn't provide executing AcroJS. Since now i don't find something like this